# Drupal : change the rss feed presentation

Tags: drupal, rss

I'm trying to manage a Drupal website made by an agency but i don't understand a bit of Drupal...and it's in bad terms with the agency.

The question is : how to manage the display of the rss.xml files.

For example, people can add event on the website with one place :

```
"ThePlace" and one title "DjTitle".
```

Actually it will be like that in the rss feed :

```
Details of place : "ThePlace"
Details of title : "DjTitle"
```

and i would like something like :

```
Tonight, "DjTitle" play in "ThePlace"
```

I looked in Administration > RSS Feed but nothing like that...
I doesn't seem to be a view
The aggregator module seem to be deactivate...
I found some clue in modules/nodes/node.module but nothing solid...

If you need to see some files, please tell me and i'll update but i don't know where to look anymore !

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

You can create a view and build the RSS feeds in the way you want. To alter the default RSS, you may have to do some customization in a custom module or two!

Comment: So you highly recommand to create a view to override the default rss.xml  ? Which modules should i custom if i prefer the second option ? Thanks.

Comment: By custom module, I meant, you own module and use hooks related RSS. I had created feeds both in code and using views. With views, it quick and you can configure in the way you want instantly!

Comment: Ok, i'll have a look on views. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing sounds like a Custom View with Taxonomy setup.  First, you'll want to check the /var/www/html/sites folder.  This folder should contain /all and /default.  If there are additional folders here, your site may be configured for "multi-site."  If your site is not a multi-site configuration, look in /var/www/html/sites/all/themes folder.  If your site IS a multi-site configuration, look in /var/www/html/sites/yoursite/themes (where yoursite = a folder name in /var/www/html/sites).

If you're not sure what theme your site is using, login to your Drupal site with the admin account to view the Administration interface.  Check out the Appearance section.  The theme listed at the top is your current default theme.  The folders in /var/www/html/sites/all/themes/ will correspond to the Themes showing under Appearance.

Once you have identified your Themes, you'll need to find the template files utilized by the RSS feed.  The naming of these files will vary depending on the way the feed was setup.  Most commonly, RSS feeds are adjusted via views-view-ros-rss.tpl.php OR views-view-rss.tpl.php.  You can learn more from any of the many tutorials out there on [customized RSS themes for Drupal](http://www.timtoon.com/2009/05/27/customizing-an-rss-feed-using-drupal-and-views/).